How to correctly create a Bicep governanceRules template?
I want to create a governanceRule using Bicep (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.security/governancerules?pivots=deployment-language-bicep).
Following the above documentation, I started out with the bare minimum (just the required properties with hard-coded values). Though, no matter what I try every request returns an errorcode (Code:BadRequest) without any indication what is wrong with the request. So it seems to be trial and error (only errors so far) here.
I am mostly unsure about the conditionSets. The documentation talks about examples The governance rule conditionSets - see examples, yet I have not been able to find any example. The only example I could come up with is the one I added in the template below. It is generated by ChatGPT, so I am hesitent to accept this as a valid value.
Does anyone have a link to further documentation so I can setup this template correctly?
resource governanceRule 'Microsoft.Security/governanceRules@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  name: 'sampleRuleName'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'Sample Governance Rule'
    description: 'This is a sample governance rule for demonstration purposes.'
    ownerSource: {
      type: 'Manually'
    }
    rulePriority: 1
    ruleType: 'Integrated'
    sourceResourceType: 'Assessments'
    conditionSets: [
      {
        query: 'type eq "Microsoft.Security/complianceResults" and properties.state eq "NonCompliant"'
      }
    ]
  }
}

Follow-up
I have tried to get this working with the link supplied by @wenbo. This link gave me useful insights and now I am sure I can create a valid template.
The deployment still fails, but at least now I know this is due to some issues at the end of Microsoft.

I find one example for you, reference
Your conditionSets seems not be in the correct pattern. Follow the sample code condtionSets
targetScope = 'subscription'

param disableManagerEmailNotification bool = false
param disableOwnerEmailNotification bool = false
param description string
param displayName string
param isDisabled bool = false
param isGracePeriod bool = true
param ownerSourceType string
param ownerSourceValue string
param remediationTimeFrame string = '7.00:00:00' //default 7 days
param rulePriority int
param ruleType string = 'Integrated'
param sourceResourceType string = 'Assessments' 

resource governanceRules 'Microsoft.Security/governanceRules@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  name: displayName
  properties: {
    conditionSets: [
      {
        conditions: [
            {
                value: [
                          'Low'
                          'Medium'
                          'High'
                        ]
                property: 'properties.metadata.severity'
                operator: 'In'
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
    description: description
    displayName: displayName
    governanceEmailNotification: {
      disableManagerEmailNotification: disableManagerEmailNotification
      disableOwnerEmailNotification: disableOwnerEmailNotification
    }
    isDisabled: isDisabled
    isGracePeriod: isGracePeriod
    ownerSource: {
      type: ownerSourceType
      value: ownerSourceValue
    }
    remediationTimeframe: remediationTimeFrame
    rulePriority: rulePriority
    ruleType: ruleType
    sourceResourceType: sourceResourceType
  }
}


Thank you for finding this. I recognize some of the options from manual configuring the rule, so I have good hopes of this working.
I will give this a go and will give an update after doing so.

Some progress... The template is accepted when using the example above. The terminal times out though. After a few minutes I checked the deployment in the Azure portal and it shows the error '{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
"code": "InternalServerError",
"message": ""
}
}'
The deployment is retried every minute, so I had to manually cancel it.
Again, not much to go on, so time for some further troubleshooting now.

Thanks for the updates, there are really few examples for the bicep template. You may need to make a lot of modifications based on your actual situation, but the overall style of the bicep will not change.
